# сброс кэша пользователей (css, js)

Tags: javascript, html, css

здравствуйте, допустим есть сайт, и 3 подгружаемых css стиля, и 2 js файла со скриптами

после изменения их содержимого, как можно сбросить кэш у всех пользователей зашедших на сайт, чтобы не дописывать к каждому src вопросительный знак и цифру новой версии файла

Answer (score 3):

Здесь поможет только обновление новой версии файла (через вопросительный знак и цифру). Конечно, можно пойти по пути Facebook и менять весь путь к файлу при его новой сборке:

```
https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3irhT4/yQ/l/ru_RU/BsLUlDIN_iw.js
```

Но намного читабельнее и понятнее выглядит подход VK:

```
/css/al/common.css?26888870024
```

Comment: Почему не добавлять версию в название файла? По-моему наглядно.